# Passing method with class as a callback method to request animation frame

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an animation class:

```
class Animation{
    constructor(id){
        let canvas = document.getElementById(id);

        this.frames = [];
        this.step = 0;
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.img =  new Image();

        Object.assign(canvas, bound);
        this.img.src = "vessle.svg";
    }
    run() {
        log('run')
        log(this)
        let frame = this.frames[this.step];
        this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

        // clear canvas
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 

        //draw images
        frame.forEach((pos)=>{
            this.drawImage( pos)
        })

        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.run);
     }
    drawImage(pos){
    //render stuff
    }

}
```

When I pass this.run in requestAnimationFrame, it seems like the rest of the values from "this" are not included in the new context. For example this.frames is not defined when I run it the second time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you passing the `this.run` in function parameter, it is just passing a callback function but not with `this` reference.

In this scenario you have to `bind` the reference of `this`

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.run.bind(this))
```

If you don't bind with `this` then inside the `callback`, `this` refers to that callback function (`run()`), not the `Animation` class.

For more see this [**reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback?answertab=oldest#tab-top) how to bind the `this` reference.

Comment: Why not just close as a duplicate if you know about our canonical question?